# Addition of multiple inputs and display in another input

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following inputs with the following classes:

20 x inputs with the class .amount1
20 x inputs with the class .amount2
20 x inputs with the class .amount3

```
<td><input class="amount1" id="input_a" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
<td><input class="amount2" id="input_a_ans" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
<td><input class="amount3" id="input_a_year" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>
```

I then have 3 inputs with the IDs:

1 x input_week
1 x input_fort
1 x input_year

```
<input class="totals" id="input_week" type="text" readonly>
<input class="totals" id="input_fort" type="text" readonly>
<input class="totals" id="input_year" type="text" readonly>
```

What I'm attempting to do is have all of the numerical values that are entered into the classes (.amount1 .amount2 .amount3) added together; so all of .amount1 added together, all of .amount2 added together and all of .amount3 added together. I then need those added amounts to be displayed in the IDs. So the sum of all of .amount1 to be displayed in #input_week e.t.c. The JS I have tried is:

```
<script>

$('.amount1').keyup(function () {
    var stockTemp = 0;
    $('.amount1').each(function () {
        stockTemp += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    });
    $('#input_week').val(stockTemp);
});

</script>
```

This JS has returned some results, namely it has worked for the above class and input, but it cannot determine decimal points, which is necessary for what I am doing. When I attempt to add the following JS:

```
<script>

$('.amount2').keyup(function () {
    var stockTemp = 0;
    $('.amount2').each(function () {
        stockTemp += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    });
    $('#input_fort').val(stockTemp);
});

</script>
```

Nothing happens at all. How can I get it to total the figures entered into the classes and have those totals displayed in the necessary IDs; inclusive of the decimal points if the values entered into the classes have decimal points.

Thanks.

Comment: The code for amount1 is working but the same for amount2 is not, am I understood right?

Comment: If you want decimals as in money, use `parseFloat().fixed(2)`

Comment: @zer00ne I tried this but couldn't figure out where to add that bit of code in the flow of the overall code.

Comment: @Undefitied Yes that is correct. The values that are entered into the input .amount1 are done manually. The values that are placed into the inputs .amount2 and .amount3 are done by some JS, namely, the amount entered into .amount1 is multiplied by 2 and that result is entered into .amount2 and then the amount in .amount 2 is multiplied by 26 and that amount is placed in .amount3. This could by why the JS isn't working for .amount2 and input_fort. But I'm unsure.

Comment: Please show us how you enter values to .amout(2 and 3)

Comment: @Undefitied Posted below.

Comment: You have 20xinput.amout1 but each of your amount* input has an id so you have 20 inputs with the same id?

Comment: @Undefitied All of my IDs are unique. My class names are shared.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I automatically prefill .amount2 and .amount3. I target the IDs to get the desired result rather than the classes though.

```
<script>

    $("input").keyup(function(){

    var getInId = $(this).attr('id');
    var getOutId = $('#'+getInId+'_ans').attr('id');
    var getOutyear = $('#'+getInId+'_year').attr('id');
    var getInVal = document.getElementById(getInId).value;

     if(!isNaN(getInVal)){ 

      var result = (getInVal * '2');
      $('#'+getOutId).val(result);

       var yearResult = (result * '26');
       $('#'+getOutyear).val(yearResult);

     }
     else{
        $('#'+getOutId).val("");
         alert("Please enter a valid number");
     }
    });

    </script>
```